# linking QuaZip with Qt 4.8.0 into project

Tags: quazip

I have a project where I want to unzip files.
I have found Quazip to be close to the implementation I want(check), but....

when build the project the compiler says

> Makefile.Release:241: warning: overriding commands for target
>   `release/moc_quazipfile.o' Makefile.Release:219: warning: ignoring
>
>   old commands for target`release/moc_quazipfile.o'
>   release\moc_quazipfile.cpp:40: warning: 'static void
>   QuaZipFile::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int,
>   void**)' redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport 
>   ignored release\moc_quazipfile.cpp:48: warning:
>   'QuaZipFile::staticMetaObjectExtraData' redeclared without dllimport
>   attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
>   release\moc_quazipfile.cpp:52: warning:
>   'QuaZipFile::staticMetaObject' redeclared without dllimport attribute 
>   after being referenced with dll linkage
>   release\moc_quazipfile.cpp:61: warning: 'virtual const QMetaObject* 
>   QuaZipFile::metaObject() const' redeclared without dllimport
>   attribute: previous dllimport ignored release\moc_quazipfile.cpp:66:
>   warning: 'virtual void* QuaZipFile::qt_metacast(const char*)'
>   redeclared without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored
>   release\moc_quazipfile.cpp:74: warning: 'virtual int
>   QuaZipFile::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)' redeclared 
>   without dllimport attribute: previous dllimport ignored
>
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `**
>   **quazip_test-build-desktop-Qt_4_8_0_for_Desktop_-*MinGW*_Qt_SDK__Release'
>   release\moc_quazipfile.cpp:48: error: definition of static data
>   member 'QuaZipFile::staticMetaObjectExtraData' of dllimport'd class 
>   mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [release/moc_quazipfile.o] Error 1
>
>   mingw32-make.exe: *** [release] Error 2 13:29:01: The process
>   "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2. Error while 
>   building project quazip_test (target: Desktop) When executing build
>   step 'Make'

.pro:

```
QT       += core gui

TARGET = quazip_test
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.0/src/3rdparty/zlib

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    quazip/quazipnewinfo.cpp \
    quazip/quazipfile.cpp \
    quazip/quazip.cpp \
    quazip/quacrc32.cpp \
    quazip/qioapi.cpp \
    quazip/moc_quazipfile.cpp \
    quazip/JlCompress.cpp \
    quazip/quaadler32.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    quazip/crypt.h \
    quazip/unzip.h \
    quazip/quaadler32.h \
    quazip/quazipnewinfo.h \
    quazip/quazipfileinfo.h \
    quazip/quazipfile.h \
    quazip/quazip_global.h \
    quazip/quazip.h \
    quazip/quacrc32.h \
    quazip/quachecksum32.h \
    quazip/JlCompress.h \
    quazip/ioapi.h \    
    quazip/zip.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "quazip/quazip.h"
#include "quazip/quazipfile.h"


namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QuaZip *temp = new QuaZip();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete ui;
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

BR

Comment: removed the moc_quazipfile. file, but didnt solve the problem

Comment: Fixed...Added unzip.c and zip.c to the project

Comment: Post your comment as an answer, so everyone can see the problem is solved. :)