# Qt: Building quazip/zlib Library error

Tags: qt, build, zlib, quazip

I am statically building the quazip library as mentioned in the following post: [linking QuaZip with Qt 4.8.0 into project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227977/linking-quazip-with-qt-4-8-0-into-project)

I get these error when I build the project:

```
/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.0/src/3rdparty/zlib/zconf.h:373:6: error: "_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE" is not defined
In file included from ../../../quazip-0.4.4/quazip/zip.h:56,
                 from ../../../quazip-0.4.4/quazip/quazip.h:31,
                 from ../../../quazip-0.4.4/quazip/quazipfile.h:30,
                 from ../../../quazip-0.4.4/quazip/quazipfile.cpp:24:

/QtSDK/QtSources/4.8.0/src/3rdparty/zlib/zlib.h:1583:32: error: "_FILE_OFFSET_BITS" is not defined
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
```

Are these known errors in zlib library? I am using zlib library in Qt 4.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a bug in your compiler.  I can't tell what version of zlib you're using, and your compiler does not show the offending line in the error message, so I can't tell exactly what the line contains.  However I suspect that these are lines that have an #if directive with the noted symbol in the expression.  Per the C standard, a symbol that is not defined is given a null value (no characters replace it) in an expression in an #if statement.  Instead your compiler is erroneously issuing an error.